# sklearn pipeline error - fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Trying to run the following:

```py
class N1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.assign(num_1="n1")

X = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "n1": [1, 2, 3],
        "n2": [3, 4, 4],
        "c1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "c2": ["x", "y", "z"],
    }
)

num_pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("num_1", N1()),
    ]
)

num_pipeline.fit(X)
# same error with: 
# num_pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I don't really see how this is happening though, or how to fix.

Full traceback:

```
    387                 return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    388             else:
--> 389                 return last_step.fit(Xt, y,
    390                                      **fit_params_last_step).transform(Xt)
    391 

TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I'm expecting to have the dataframe `X` returned with the added column `num_1`

Comment: you can just call transform as that where change is: `new_df=num_pipeline.transform(X)` if the fit function is involved, it needs y or y=None which is there in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, `fit` requires also an `X` and an optional `y` parameter so probably `Pipeline` tries to pass these.

Maybe try to define it like so:

```py
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self
```

You might also want to look at [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#function-transformer).

Comment: Thanks, re "_ Usually, fit requires also an X and an optional y parameter so probably Pipeline tries to pass these_", is there a link to any documentation on this?

Comment: @baxx Sure, scikit-learn has extensive documentation: [fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-fit), [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators).

Comment: thanks, tho from the doc: "It usually takes some samples X, targets y", suggests this isn't a strict requirement, how to know what's necessary?

Comment: @baxx This I suppose depends on the specific transformation or model you try to include in the pipeline.

Comment: ok, so in this case (the case of my original post), why is it necessary to have `y = None` ? the docs don't seem to say it's necessary, so I don't understand the logic / reasoninfg

Comment: Yes, I also find the docs not enough explicit about that. One possible reason behind this is that when you need a custom transformer, you can use `FunctionTransformer` (and avoid these headaches? :) ).

You can get a hint, nonetheless, from the documentation of `Pipeline`'s [`fit` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit). Finally, the error message's traceback gives also a hint: `last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)`